# Avoid foreground becomes into background on background substractor using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want to make a hand detector using OpenCV. I've created a background substractor using the next code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

global fgMask
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
backSub = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(detectShadows=False)

firstImage = True

crop_width = 300
crop_height = 300

camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1024)
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1024)

while True:
    try:
        ret, image = camera.read()

        image = cv2.flip(image, 1)

        roi = image[0:crop_height, 0:crop_width]

        if firstImage:
            fgMask = backSub.apply(roi)
            firstImage = False
        else:
            fgMask = backSub.apply(roi, None, 0)

        cv2.imshow("Original", image)
        cv2.imshow("Mask", fgMask)
        cv2.imshow("Roi", roi)

        k = cv2.waitKey(10)
        if k == 27:  # press ESC to exit
            camera.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

I add images during few seconds using apply method in order to the model learns background, and the mask generated by model is black (everything is ok at this point)

[image: Black Mask]

when I put my hand, the mask is ok

[image: hand mask]

but after a while the hand begins to disapper

[image: hand disappers]

I have read you can set learningRate parameter to 0 to avoid the model trains using new frames, but I get the same result (hand disappers after a while). I've tried different learning parameters but the result is always same.

Comment: Without any code is hard to find out what it is happening.

Comment: I added example code

Comment: If you fix your camera then you only need to choose a static background and use different frame or running average algorithm.